# SQL eRROR :Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I don't know why this is happening error

I'm trying to simply connect my database to jdbc

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

In the url `jdbc:mysel://localhost:test` you set the host as `localhost` and the port as `test`

There is no such port called `test`, you need to provide a port number.

Most likely you are using the default port for mysql, so you might need to provide one at all.